# calculate value for resistor in

Tags: operational-amplifier, resistors, amplifier, feedback, inverting-amplifier

I have an LMC6001 op-amp, and I would like to build the ph probe amplifier featured in the datasheet. Unfortunately, I am not sure what R9 is or should be.
Does R9 control slew rate? How would I calculate the value for R9 feed back resistor?

[image]

Comment: You don't want to give the value TI gave you?

Comment: Maybe it isn't clear, but the line that says "R4, 9 100k" means that both R4 and R9 should be 100 kohms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of R9 is specified in your list of parts.  It's in the same line as R4.

R9 does two things.  It, in conjunction with R4, sets the gain of the 2nd stage.  It also acts as a low-pass filter in conjunction with C1.

[Edit]

Oops.  I goofed.  Looking closer at the diagram, I see that I mixed up the (-) & (+) inputs on the 2nd op-amp.  I have modified my answer.

Comment: Ah, I see what they did there. Thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2):

R9 and R4 set the DC gain of the 2nd stage. In this case, having R4 = R9 = 100k ohms gives a gain of -1.

R9 and C1 set the cut-off frequency of the low-pass filter formed by the 2nd stage. In this case 100k and 2.2 uF gives about 0.75 Hz.

If you want to adjust R9, you should probably adjust R4 as well to maintain the gain of -1. If you want to adjust the cut-off frequency it's probably easier to adjust C1 instead.